# Please explain these commands in the code

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

```
n=int(input("Enter number of rows: "))
a=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    a[i].append(1)
    for j in range(1,i):
        a[i].append(a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j])
    if(n!=0):
        a[i].append(1)
for i in range(n):
    print("   "*(n-i),end=" ",sep=" ")
    for j in range(0,i+1):
        print('{0:6}'.format(a[i][j]),end=" ",sep=" ")
    print()
```

my qestions:
1-please explain the 7th line's append index(I didnt undersand what did it try to say with `a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j]`

2-why do we need to put an empty print at the end? `print()`

Comment: "why do we need to put an empty print at the end? `print()`" You don't *need* to do anything, but an empty `print` like that prints a newline, so presumably, whoever wrote that code intended to print a newline.

Comment: But essentially "a[i].append(a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j])" is an expression of the recursive definition of Pascal's triangle, stated plainly, each number is the sum of the two numbers above it, i.e. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/PascalTriangleAnimated2.gif

Answer (score 1):

So apparently this code generates a ASCII version of pascal's triangle.

```
$ python3 testing.py
Enter number of rows: 5
                     1 
                  1      1 
               1      2      1 
            1      3      3      1 
         1      4      6      4      1
```

1).  the code here:

```
a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j]
```

adds the first-row-first-column number with the first-row-second-column number to generate pascal's triangle.

2). this statement here:

```
print()
```

prints a newline.

Comment: I didnt understand exactly what `a[i-1][j-1]+a[i-1][j]` is doing. Where can i get the details about this syntax?

Comment: a[i][j] is acessing the  i-th row and the j-th column in the array.

Comment: [i-1] is not i-to-1, but rather i minus 1.

Comment: And why do we do [i-1][j-1] do we multiply them or sth?

Comment: its not multiplication, but rather a coordinate, for example a[1][3] is the value for (1,3) in the array.

Comment: whatever the sum of the values at (1,3) and (1,4) are.